# How to parse AWS Redshift User Activity Log into an object?

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-redshift

I am trying to parse AWS Redshift User Activity Log (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/db-auditing.html) into an object.

**Redshift User Activity Log**

```
'2016-11-16T08:00:13Z UTC [ db=dev user=rdsdb pid=30500 userid=1 xid=1520 ]' LOG: SELECT 1
```

**Python RedshiftUserActivityLog object**

```
class RedshiftUserActivtyLog (object):    
        def __init__(self, record_time, db,
                 user, pid, user_id, xid,
                 query):
        super(RedshiftUserActivtyLog , self).__init__()

        self.record_time = record_time
        self.db = db
        self.user = user
        self.pid = pid
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.xid = xid
        self.query = query
```

My current solution is to remove the unnecessary characters like '[, ], UTC, LOG, :', split the log by space into a list. After that, convert the list into the object.

Can anyone suggest me the better way to do this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concoct a regex and then populate your object from the `groupdict()` of the match, like

```
regex = re.compile(r'\'(?P<time>[\d\-:T]+)\w UTC \[ db=(?P<db>\w+) user=(?P<user>\w+) pid=(?P<pid>\d+) userid=(?P<userid>\d+) xid=(?P<xid>\d+) \]\' LOG:(?P<query>.*)')
match = regex.search(log)
if match:
    userActivity = RedshiftUserActivtyLog(
        record_time=match.group('time'),
        db=match.group('db'),
        user=match.group('user'),
        pid=match.group('pid'),
        user_id=match.group('user_id'),
        xid=match.group('xid'),
        log=match.group('log')
    )
```

But actually your way is also quite legit, and maybe even faster.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to parse the Redshift audit logs is via [Amazon Redshift Spectrum](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/spectrum/).

There is a nice blog post about it [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyze-database-audit-logs-for-security-and-compliance-using-amazon-redshift-spectrum/).